# DRY way of calling a method in every rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Along the same lines as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863613/global-methods-in-ruby-on-rails-models), I want to call `acts_as_reportable` inside every model so I can do one-off manual reports in the console in my dev environment (with a dump of the production data).

What's the best way to do this?  Putting `acts_as_reportable if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development"` in every model is getting tedious and isn't very DRY at all.  Everyone says monkey patching is the devil, but a mixin seems overkill.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a Reportable class and deriving all the models from it?

```
class Reportable
  acts_as_reportable if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development"
end

class MyModel < Reportable
end
```

Comment: Ha!  This is basically the equivalent of the ApplicationController, as Throlkim mentions.  If this was such a good idea - which it looks it to me - why isn't it done already?  It'd be a great way to further DRY things up.

I think I might just have to start doing this as a matter of course.  As it stands now, I'm gonna have to go make some regex to find and replace all of my Class lines.  I think I'll go for the more generic ApplicationModel though. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

For me the best way will be to add it into the ActiveRecord::Base in the initializer.  I believe the acts_as_reportable is a mixin under the hood.  By doing this, when you will be able to call all the method that came with acts_as_reportable in all your models in development environment only.

I will do it in the `config/initializers` directory, in a file called `model_mixin.rb` or anything that you wish.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_reportable if (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development")
end
```

The argument of using monkey patch is dirty depends on yourself and how readable the code is, in my opinion, use what you are comfortable with. The feature are there to be used and it always depends on the user.

Comment: This does look like the fastest and most practical way to go for now.  I supposed I better read up a bit on why monkey patching is so bad first, before I commit myself to a life of misery.

Answer (score 1):

I use a mixin for common methods across all my models:

```
 module ModelMixins
    # Splits a comma separated list of categories and associates them
    def process_new_categories(new_categories)
      unless new_categories.nil?
        for title in new_categories.split(",")
          self.categories << Category.find_or_create_by_title(title.strip.capitalize)
        end
        self.update_counter_caches
      end
   end
 end
```

I considered doing it in other ways, but to me this seems to be the most legitimate way of DRYing up your models. A model equivalent of the ApplicationController would be a neat solution, though I'm not sure how you'd go about that, or whether there's a decent argument against having one.

Comment: I saw this way of doing it, and even though it seemed to be overkill I did think a bit about it.  As far as I can see though, this will add a new method to the class.  I want to call some other code that adds methods to the class, not directly add the methods myself.  So it'd have to be some initialize method or something and now my head hurts...

I think an ApplicationModel is a great idea (although others obviously don't, otherwise we'd have it already) and is something I've thought about for various reasons for a while.  Looks like Draco Ater (above) has the right idea...